# nginx root directory for laravel

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, laravel-5

I would be very grateful if someone could answer.
I am trying to install my laravel project to virtual host. The server 
runs on nginx.
Everything is ok except assets file.

The problem is the server does not load assets files. To be more exact:

```
asset()
```

function doesnt point to `public` path.

But the URLs (routes) are working perfect.

I copied htaccess files from public path to root.

Here is my htaccess files content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Any helps guys! Thank you very much!

Comment: Clarify the configuration. htaccess is Apache related config file.

Comment: Could you post your nginx server block as well?

Comment: Thank you very much guys!
I just had to change root directory of nginx to public path.